# MySQL Drop foreign key Error 152

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, alter-table

I am trying to drop a number of foreign keys using:

```
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_table_users1` , DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_table_accounts1` , DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_table_data1` ;
```

but it returns the error:

```
Error on rename of './db/table' to './db/#sql2-179c-288289' (errno: 152)
```

I have run `SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS` which says:

```
120725 12:38:37 Error in dropping of a foreign key constraint of table db/table,
in SQL command
ALTER TABLE `table` DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_table_users1` , DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_table_accounts1` , DROP FOREIGN KEY `fk_table_data1` 
Cannot find a constraint with the given id fk_table_users1.
```

`SHOW CREATE TABLE 'table'` output:

```
CREATE TABLE `table` (
 `id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
 `data_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `account_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
 `status` enum('pending','complete') NOT NULL default 'pending',
 `created_at` datetime NOT NULL,
 `created_by` int(11) NOT NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`id`),
 KEY `fk_orders_users1` (`created_by`),
 KEY `fk_orders_data1` (`data_id`),
 KEY `fk_orders_accounts1` (`account_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

However when I look at the structure via phpmyadmin it lists the foreign key with the same name. Do I need to do something else before I can drop the foreign keys?

Comment: Please post the output of ``SHOW CREATE TABLE `table`;``.

Comment: @eggyal edited my post with the output

Comment: I don't see *any* foreign key constraints there...

Comment: thanks for pointing that out. we use a migrations script and it looks like it didn't add the foreign keys

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are no foreign keys. Refer [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) which says

```
KEY is normally a synonym for INDEX.
```

So basically in table you have created indexes, not foreign keys. [For Foreign Key info, Click here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-foreign-key-constraints.html)

Comment: A small but possibly good one: I had this issue. Using this answer I double checked myself and noticed I attempted to delete the KEY that is needed for the constraint. A small fix in the 'drop' statement to change the name from the key name to the constraint name - and violla!

Answer (score 2):

You need to temporarily drop the constraint so that you can remove it.

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;

and then turn them on again after you drop the foreign key:

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=1;

Comment: You probably mean `=1` in the last line ;)

Answer (score 0):

first drop foreign key then delete column

alter table 'table name' drop foreign key 'constraint id ;

if you don't know constraint id create database dump in that constraint id is available in dump file ..

then delete column..

Answer (score 0):

The index name and constraint name may not be same. You should delete constraint first using code: `ALTER TABLE tablename DROP FOREIGN KEY constraintname`